# change height of a specific custom uitableviewcell when touched

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview, cocoa-touch

/*
i want to tap the uitableviewcell and its height should increase and than when i tap again on the same cell the size of cell should reduce. The size of custom cell is 293, but it should be 217 in start , when i touch it , it should be 293 and if i touch it again it should go back to 217. The same happens for all the cells. Please see the image links to have a better understanding. 
- https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6FUABgh-tDmZ3BteVhpWFU2d3M/view?usp=sharing
- https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6FUABgh-tDmbklNRVhqT0lnbVE/view?usp=sharing
*/

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    selectedrow = -1;

    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"SelectedResturentCell"  bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"SelectedResturentCell"];

    NormalSize = 217;
    ExpandedSize = 290;

    [buyBtnTpd.layer setCornerRadius:2.0];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 5;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SelectedResturentCell";
    cell = (SelectedResturentCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    [cell.firstBtnOutlet addTarget:self action:@selector(cellBtnTpd) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    int row = [indexPath row];
    selectedrow = row;
    //[tableView reloadData];
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView endUpdates];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ( selectedrow == [indexPath row])
    {
        NSIndexPath *index = [tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
        cellHeight = [self tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:index];
        if (cellHeight < ExpandedSize)
        {
            return  ExpandedSize;
        }

        else
        return  NormalSize;
    }

    else return 217;
}
```

Comment: so what happenning right now? when launch what it cell size it showing?
when you tap on cell what is happenning?
when you again tap is it coming back to normal size ?

Comment: Dear please see the links for a better understanding.
Problem: change the height of a specific cell on which i tap.
Must be doing something wrong in here (heightForRowAtIndexPath and didSelectRowAtIndexPath)